# PHP/CSS find two color word in string, change its color

Tags: php, css

PHP/CSS find two word in string, change its color for display. 
Having a problem, can't find its solution, any suggestions? thanks.

```
<?php
$word = '<font color = "blue">blue</font>';
$num = '<font color = "blue">123</font>';
$text = $word.$num;
echo '$text='.$text.'<br>';

$blue='blue';
$find = '<font color="blue">'.$blue.'</font>';
$re='<font color="green">'.$blue.'</font>';

$check = str_replace($find,$re,$text);

echo '$find='.$find.'<br>';
echo '$re='.$re.'<br>';
echo '$check='.$check.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Please give more details about your problem. What should happen? What happen instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have spaces before and after "=" in your original text:

```
color = "blue"
```

And don't have spaces in `$find`:

```
color="blue"
```

To avoid this use regular expression:

```
<?php
$word = '<font color = "blue">blue</font>';
$num = '<font color = "blue">123</font>';
$text = $word.$num;

$blue='blue';
$find = '<font color.*?=.*?"blue">'.$blue.'<\/font>';
$re='<font color="green">'.$blue.'</font>';

$check = preg_replace("/$find/", $re, $text);

echo '$check='.$check."<br>\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
$check=<font color="green">blue</font><font color = "blue">123</font><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think this will solve your problem

```
<?php
$word = '<font color = "blue">blue</font>';
$num = '<font color = "blue">123</font>';
$text = $word.$num;
echo $text.'='.$text.'<br>';

$blue='blue';
$find = '<font color="blue">'.$blue.'</font>';
$re='<font color="green">'.$blue.'</font>';

$check = str_replace($find,$re,$text);

echo $find.'='.$find.'<br>';
echo $re.'='.$re.'<br>';
echo $check.'='.$check.'<br>';
?>
```